# BDD on Android with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, bdd

I am considering an approach fo BDD tests on Android.

The sample app — a simple messenger — has been made in Kotlin, so will be the tests.

I ended up with something like this :

```
class IGotYourMessage : Scenario<LoginActivity>(LoginActivity::class.java, {

    Given()
        .iAmOnLoginScreen()
    .When()
        .iLogin()
    .Then()
        .iSeeContactsList()
        .iSeeAContact()
    .When()
        .iSelectAContact()
    .Then()
        .iSeeMessagesList()
        .iSeeAMessage()
    .With(hashMapOf(
        "email" to "john@doe.com",
        "password" to "foo",
        "contactFirstName" to "Jane",
        "contactLastName" to "Doe",
        "messageText" to "Hello John!"
    ))
    .With(hashMapOf(
        "email" to "jane@doe.com",
        "password" to "bar",
        "contactFirstName" to "John",
        "contactLastName" to "Doe",
        "messageText" to "Hello John!"
    ))
})
```

I ended up with this assessment :

- The Given is a start state
- The When is an action
- The Then is an end state
- The Then is also a start state for the next action

So I can Given -> When -> Then -> When -> Then.

---

Each `With` is a test case providing its own data.

Each "step" is an extension on the `Given`, `When` or `Then` classes as in:

```
fun Then.iSeeAContact() {
    add({
        (it["contactFirstName"] as String).canSee()
        (it["contactLastName"] as String).canSee()
    })
    return this
}
```

The `canSee` method is an extension on `String`, using [Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html):

```
fun String.canSee(): String {
    onView(withText(this)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    return this
}
```

So! I am here to get feedback, criticism and/or suggestions.

*I do not really know if it the place for this kind of question (is it one?).*

Comment: Probably more on-topic at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Also, you might want to check out Jake Wharton on the "Robot pattern": https://realm.io/news/kau-jake-wharton-testing-robots/.

Comment: Thanks @nhaarman I missed that.
But, his *one case* approach bugs me. Writing the same test twice for different data set can lead to an (unintentional) alteration of one test but the other. This would make the tests irrelevants so the app not robust.